# Is it possible to run the XSLT file through SHELL script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the below XSLT file and I just want to run it through SHELL script.

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="test-method[@status = 'FAIL']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Sample XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test-result>
    <test-method status="PASS" name="beforeTestSetup" is-config="true" duration-ms="705" started-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z">
        <params>
            <param index="0">
                <value>
                    <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>
                </value>
            </param>
        </params>   
    </test-method>
    <test-method status="FAIL" name="beforeTestSetup" is-config="true" duration-ms="805" started-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z">
        <params>
            <param index="0">
                <value>
                    <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>
                </value>
            </param>
        </params>   
    </test-method>
    <test-method status="PASS" name="TEST" is-config="true" duration-ms="905" started-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z">
        <params>
            <param index="0">
                <value>
                    <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>
                </value>
            </param>
        </params>   
    </test-method>      
</test-result>
```

I just want to run the above xslt against the sample XML through SHELL script and I want to use it in the JENKINS shell script editor.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I suppose you'd need to use an xslt processor tool like `xsltproc`. E.g. `xsltproc <xsltfile> <xmlfile>`

Comment: Can you give some example. It will be very helpful to implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an XSLT processor to apply an XSLT style file to an XML input file.

We use `xsltproc` for this and the shell command is

```
xsltproc [other_options] --output output.xml style.xslt input.xml
```

See the xsltproc manual page for the other_options. In a nutshell:

```
SYNOPSIS
       xsltproc [[-V | --version] [-v | --verbose] [{-o | --output} {FILE | DIRECTORY}] |
                --timing | --repeat | --debug | --novalid | --noout | --maxdepth VALUE | --html |
                --encoding ENCODING  | --param PARAMNAME PARAMVALUE  |
                --stringparam PARAMNAME PARAMVALUE  | --nonet | --path "PATH(S)" | --load-trace |
                --catalogs | --xinclude | [--profile | --norman] | --dumpextensions | --nowrite |
                --nomkdir | --writesubtree PATH | --nodtdattr] [STYLESHEET] {XML-FILE | -}
```